# Multiple margins in Atom Editor?

Tags: settings, atom-editor

Using [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/), I can change the position of the vertical margin from

```
File > Settings > Preferred Line Length
```

Is there a way to add multiple margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you install the [omni-ruler plugin](https://atom.io/packages/omni-ruler).

[image: omni-ruler plugin example]

Answer (score -1):

I'm amazed as how dificult is for everyone to understand the problem.
Being a "stack overflow" user, you would expect to find many user with experience on the problem of working with [fixed-width-fields] text files.

is not a text file with a long line.
is data contained in those lines, that need to be make easier for human eye to check.

that being said, the besto solution so far fo me is:

https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/column-markers.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.